# Where .swiftmodule need to be placed for swift debugging (xcode with custom executable xcscheme)

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an IOS GUI app which is mainly written in ObjC and does occasionally call swift methods (located in a single swift module).

The app is build via 'make' on the command line without XCode/xcodebuild (just straight clang/swift command lines) and works fine so far.

Now when it comes to run/debug I have a small wrapper XCode project (type External build system) which calls 'make' in a "Run script" phase , produces the executable and is debuggable via a custom shared xcscheme.

This works fine for objective C.
If I try however to debug into the Swift code I get the infamous message

```
error: Error in auto-import:
failed to get module 'myswiftmodule' from AST context
```

This is because lldb doesn't find the AST info for the swift module.
But I did link the executable with

```
    clang ...  -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker myswiftmodule.swiftmodule
```

I thought that would be sufficient, but apparently not.

I see that XCode places in a straightforward Swift project the swiftmodule(s)
in a sibling directory of the appdir

app is in

```
    /XCode...Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp.app/myapp
```

swiftmodules are in

```
    /XCode...Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp.swiftmodule/i386.swiftmodule
```

and

```
    /XCode...Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp.swiftmodule/x86_64.swiftmodule
```

I guess this is somehow a hint for the debugger, but I can't find any documentation mentioning this.

I tried the same structure in my xcscheme but no luck..still the auto-import fails.

Any pointers are much appreciated.